# Glivenko-Cantelli for $k$-points

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f$ be a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random iid variables, all of law $\mu$. Then Glivenko-Cantelli's theorem allows us to derive the convergence in law $\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} \delta_{f(X_i)} \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\rightarrow} f_* \mu$.

**Do we have a $2$-point Glivenko-Cantelli's theorem?** That is, let $f$ be a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$. Do we have the convergence in law $\frac{1}{n(n-1)} \sum_{\substack{i,j \in \{1,\cdots,n\}\\ i\neq j}} \delta_{f(X_i,X_j)} \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\rightarrow} f_* (\mu \otimes \mu)$?

**And a $k$-point Glivenko-Cantelli's theorem?**

I don't know if it is possible to prove $2$-point Glivenko-Cantelli from the usual one, since the family $(X_i,X_j)_{\substack{i,j \in \mathbb{N}\\ i\neq j}}$ is not independent. But still, most of the pairs of members of the family are independent pairs...

Comment: Consider for instance the strong law of large numbers for a strictly stationary (not i.i.d.) time series: this is a central result of ergodic theory. This result shows that the sequence $\bar{X}_n$ always converges to a limit, but in general this limit may be random. For this reason, one has to take greater care in general when dealing with non i.i.d. sequences. For the case you are wondering about, which is of an even stronger nature, you can try to consult the following paper: https://sites.stat.washington.edu/jaw/JAW-papers/jaw-79-SPAppl.pdf and see if you find something useful there.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is positive, though I don't see any reason to speak of Glivenko-Cantelli here, as it concerns uniform convergence.

For notational simplicity, I will consider $m=2$. We want to show that there is some event of full probability where for each $g\in C_b(\mathbb R)$
$$
S_n(g) := \frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{1\le i\neq j\le n} g\big(f(X_i,X_j)\big)\to \mathbb{E}[g\big(f(X_1,X_2)\big)]=:E(g), n\to\infty. 
$$
Denoting $h=g(f)$, the almost sure convergence here follows from the strong law of large numbers for $U$-statistics. However, the issue, as in the case $m=1$, is with exceptional sets depending on $g$. And as for $m=1$, this issue is resolved in two steps:

*Step 1. Localization*.  Denote $g_N(y) = g(y)\mathbf 1_{|y|\le N}$. Write
$$
|S_n(g) - S_n(g_N)|\le ||g||_\infty \cdot S_n(\mathbf 1_{|y|>N}),
$$
whence (appealing to the SLLN for $U$-statistics)
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty} |S_n(g) - S_n(g_N)|\le ||g||_\infty \cdot \mathbb{P}(|f(X_1,X_2)|>N)
$$
almost surely for every integer $N\ge 1$. Since there are countably many, we can choose an exceptional event independent of $N$ (not that it does not depend on $g$). Also we have $|E(g) - E(g_N)|\le ||g||_\infty \cdot \mathbb{P}(|f(X_1,X_2)|>N)$, so
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty} |S_n(g) - E(g)|\le \limsup_{n\to \infty} |S_n(g_N) - E(g_N)| + 2||g||_\infty \cdot \mathbb{P}(|f(X_1,X_2)|>N). 
$$
Since $\mathbb{P}(|f(X_1,X_2)|>N)\to 0$, $N\to\infty$, it suffices to show that $S_n(g_N) \to E(g_N)$, $n\to\infty$, on some event of full probability independent of $g$ and $N$.

*Step 2. Separability*. For each $N\ge 1$, choose a dense countable subset  $\mathcal C_N \subset C([-N,N])$. Thanks to the SLLN for $U$-statistics, for each $h\in \mathcal C_N$, $S_n(h) \to E(h)$, $n\to\infty$, almost surely$^*$. Since $\bigcup_{N\ge 1}\mathcal C_N$ is countable, the convergence holds on some $\Omega'$ having full probability and independent of $h$ and $N$. Choosing for any function $g\in C([-N,N])$ and any $\varepsilon>0$ a function $h\in \mathcal C_N$ with $||g-h||_\infty<\varepsilon$, as in Step 1, we get
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} |S_n(g) - E(g)| \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} |S_n(h) - E(h)| + 2\varepsilon  = 2\varepsilon
$$
on $\Omega'$, whence we conclude by letting $\varepsilon\to 0$.

---

$^*$ Here is a slight abuse of notation, as in this step I speak rather of $S_n(\tilde h)$ where $\tilde h = h$ on $[-N,N]$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: I mentioned the keywords Glivenko-Cantelli because I don't know the exact keywords for "convergence of empirical measures to true measure".

Comment: Moreover, I don't know the strong law of large numbers for $U$-statistics. Can you give me a reference about this? Thank you!

Comment: @Plop, e.g. Serfling *Approximation Theorems of Mathematical Statistics* Chapter 5

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at it.

Comment: Mmmmh, I guess there is a mistake: you write $g(x_1,x_2)$ at some point, but $g$ takes only one argument.

Comment: @Plop, indeed, thanks, fixed.